# where clause in insert statement

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone i have two tables tests and questions. Each test have many questions and there are many test. What i would like to do is dynamically redirect user for creating question same as update we do for update.

This code is for inserting

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['add'])){
$insert=$connection->query(
"INSERT INTO questions
(question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,correct_answ,marks,related_to_test)
VALUES
('$question','$ans1','$ans2','$ans3','$ans4','$correct_answ','$marks','$related_to_test')
where related_to_test='".$_REQUEST['add']."'");
//None of them is working
set related_to_test='".$_REQUEST['add']."'");
}
```

This code redirect user from test page to create a question

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="questions.php?add=<?php echo $result['test_id']; ?>">
<i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>  
Add Question                                            
</a>
```

The code above inserts record but all fields are blink except related_to_test or the one the page is redirected to.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: never seen where clause in insert query

Comment: Why would you apply a `WHERE` clause on an `INSERT` statement? Inserting is not bound to conditions. You either do insert or you don't. You may want to use `UPDATE` or `REPLACE` instead. (Conditional inserting applies indeed, when using `INSERT ... SELECT` which is not the case here).

Comment: @preetam I have. `insert into table1 select col1, col2 from table2 where col3 = 123` ;)

Comment: to add question in the same test it is been redirected from

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: i was talking about simply insert clause. its compound query

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `INSERT` with `WHERE clause` unless it's `WHERE NOT EXISTS`,so just do:

```
INSERT INTO components(Quantity) VALUES(x)
```

Comment: The field is not unique. it's a foreign key field it can be duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
INSERT INTO questions(question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,correct_answ,marks,related_to_test)
VALUES
('$question','$ans1','$ans2','$ans3','$ans4','$correct_answ','$marks','$related_to_test');
```

**Some Comment::** use this as it should work fine cause you cannaot use where claues in the insert. But still gonna work as where clause look at the column name **related_to_test** in the query, its Values is **$related_to_test**, so in my view its gonna insert the values at right place. hope i explain it properly.

Comment: thank you for you help but still blink fields when insert is done

Comment: The only thing i found is when i add $_REQUEST['add'] all field get blink when inserted to database